# how to calculate between to different models field without having connection

Tags: python, django

hi i need to calculate between to different models field without having any connection
imagine i have two models (tables) i want to get profit and income in a storage , `Model1` for selling purpose and the other for costs of the company , i need to know profit and incomes , `field_1` all selling prices and `field_2` all costs of the company

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.IntegerField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    field_2 = models.IntegerField()
```

can i calculate something like this `model1__field1 - model2__field2` ?

i much appreciate your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this first you need to get the both models object.

```
obj1 = Model1.objects.get(pk=1)
obj2 = Model2.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Now you can calculate the difference.

```
diff = obj1.field_1 - obj2.field_2
```